# How to reduce delay in real time LiveCharts graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I want to plot e.g. sine with given frequency using LiveCharts library. I have started with official tutorial "Constant changes", but I can't achieve similiar behaviour even for smallest amount of samples. I'm using default tutorial code.

There is said: " in this case we are disabling animations in the X axis to get a better visual effect". But I can't see it in example code, and that code doesn't display "fixed" chart like in example animation. What's more if the chart is scrolling the animation is not smooth, and there are small skips on adding new value to series.

Is there any way to disable animation of x axis or another way to remove little jumps on each step (adding a new value to series)?

[Animations disabled (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6URDF.gif)

[Animations enabled (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ev55.gif)

Answer (score 2):

multim

I'm assuming you've read the Performance Tips section - Disable Animations -  and that still didn't work?

[Live Charts - Performance Tips](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Performance%20Tips)

```
    <lvc:CartesianChart DisableAnimations="True" />
```

Edit: I am pretty new to Live Charts!

Comment: When I disable animations the plot is getting even less smooth.

But I keep Hoverable="False" and DataTooltip={x:Null}. 
I can't use AddRange() method because of logic of this app (plot won't look as I wish then).

Comment: @multim If I come across anything, I will give you a yell. I do not have a solution right now, as I have not had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think free version is suitable for real-time workload. Anything other than "Hello World"-esque implementations will have serious performance issues even if you do follow all of the performance tips.

Geared extension seems to work fine with examples provided by the author, but has a lot of unresolved issues people reported when switching from free to geared version. This includes but is not limited to: threading issues, zoom issues, series collection binding etc.

Comment: That's what I found out later. I've finally end up with writing custom UserControl using WPF's Canvas and Shapes. When buffered and written to bitmap it works pretty well.